# Get Access property of a CodeElement

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, extensibility, envdte

I'm writing  an Add-in for VS 2010. Can't find answer for a question - How can i get the Access property of a CodeElement if it has that one.

I was trying reflection, but no results.
Ex. CodeElement is a class method

```
public void GetAccess (CodeElement codeElement)

{

      object code = codeElement;
      Type t = code.GetType();
      t.GetProperty("Access") = vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic;

}
```

But it doesnt work..

Help, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access is only available on some types of CodeElements, so you'll need to check for the type of CodeElement you have, cast to the specific type and then retrieve the property.

Example:

```
if (codeElement.Kind == vsCMElementFunction)
{
    return ((CodeFunction)codeElement).Access;
}
else if (codeElement.Kind == vsCMElementProperty)
{
    return ((CodeProperty)codeElement).Access;
}
```