# Skip private properties when iterating class members using EnvDte

Tags: c#, t4, envdte

I have written this helper method to get the properties from a class, but it also gets the private properties. How can I get public properties only?

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetProperties(CodeClass @class)
{
    return @class.Members.Cast<CodeElement>()
    .Where(ce => ce.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty)
    .Select(ce => ce.Name)
    .ToList();
}
```

**Update:** You can look here for a more in depth blog about this technique http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/02/05/typed-javascript-contracts-using-t4-templates/

Comment: Why don't you use reflection?

Comment: Maybe this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014592/get-access-property-of-a-codeelement

Comment: Can't use reflection, EnvDTE parsing the .cs text files at design time. I create a javascript using a T4 template that proxies our Commands and Queries (CQRS)

Comment: Thanks Ash, that seems to be what I'm after, will test now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Ash's comment lead me to the answer. So now I have this T4 template

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".js" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ include file="..\T4\Automation.ttinclude"#><#
var project = VisualStudioHelper.GetProject("MyApp.Core.Contracts");      
var contracts = GetSubClasses("MyApp.Core.Contracts.Commands.Command", project)
    .Concat(GetSubClasses("MyApp.Core.Contracts.Queries.Query", project));

#>(function(MyApp) {
    function buildContract(contract) {
        return { type: contract.constructor.type, data: ko.toJSON(contract) };
    }
    var url = "api/commandQuery";
    MyApp.cqrs = {
        sendQuery: function(query, callback) {
            $.getJSON(url, buildContract(query), callback);
        },
        sendCommand: function(command) {
            MyApp.utils.post(url, buildContract(command));
        }
    };
<#


foreach(var contract in contracts) {
        #>  
    <#
    foreach(var part in BuildNameSpace(contract)) {
        #><#= part #>
    <#
    }

    var properties = GetProperties(contract).Select(p => CamelCased(p.Name)).ToList();
    var args = string.Join(", ", properties);

    #>

    window.<#= contract.FullName #> = function(<#= args #>) {<#
    foreach(var property in properties) {#>

        this.<#= property #> = <#= property #>;<#
    }
    #>

    };
    window.<#= contract.FullName #>.type = "<#= contract.FullName #>";
<#
}
#>
})(window.MyApp = window.MyApp || {});
<#+

private static IEnumerable<string> BuildNameSpace(CodeClass @class)
{
    return BuildNameSpace(@class.Namespace.Name.Split('.'), "window", new List<string>());
}            

private static IEnumerable<string> BuildNameSpace(IEnumerable<string> @namespace, string parent, List<string> parts)
{
    var part = @namespace.FirstOrDefault();
    if (part == null) return parts;

    var current = string.Format("{0}.{1}", parent, part);
    parts.Add(string.Format("{0} = ({0} || {{}});", current));
    return BuildNameSpace(@namespace.Skip(1), current, parts);
}

public IEnumerable<CodeClass> GetSubClasses(string baseClass, Project project)
{
    return VisualStudioHelper       
        .CodeModel
        .GetAllCodeElementsOfType(project.CodeModel.CodeElements, EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass, false)
        .Cast<CodeClass>()
        .Where(c => GetInheritance(c).Any(b => b.FullName == baseClass) && !c.IsAbstract)
        .ToList(); 
}


public IEnumerable<CodeClass> GetInheritance(CodeClass @class) 
{
    return GetInheritance(@class, new List<CodeClass>());
}

public IEnumerable<CodeClass> GetInheritance(CodeClass @class, List<CodeClass> collection) 
{
    foreach(CodeClass @base in @class.Bases) 
    {
        collection.Add(@base);
        GetInheritance(@base, collection);
    }

    return collection;
}

public string CamelCased(string pascalCased) {
    return pascalCased.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + pascalCased.Substring(1);
}

public IEnumerable<CodeProperty> GetProperties(CodeClass @class)
{
    if (@class == null) 
        return new List<CodeProperty>();

    var baseProperties = GetProperties(@class.Bases.Cast<CodeClass>().FirstOrDefault());

    return baseProperties.Concat(@class
        .Members
        .Cast<CodeElement>()
        .Where(ce => ce.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty)
        .Cast<CodeProperty>()
        .Where(p => p.Access == vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic));
    }
 #>
```

It outputs a JS that looks like this, code completion works from VS2012 with Resharper

```
(function(MyApp) {
    function buildContract(contract) {
        return { type: contract.constructor.type, data: ko.toJSON(contract) };
    }
    var url = "api/commandQuery";
    MyApp.cqrs = {
        sendQuery: function(query, callback) {
            $.getJSON(url, buildContract(query), callback);
        },
        sendCommand: function(command) {
            MyApp.utils.post(url, buildContract(command));
        }
    };

    window.MyApp = (window.MyApp || {});
    window.MyApp.Core = (window.MyApp.Core || {});
    window.MyApp.Core.Contracts = (window.MyApp.Core.Contracts || {});
    window.MyApp.Core.Contracts.Commands = (window.MyApp.Core.Contracts.Commands || {});

    window.MyApp.Core.Contracts.Commands.FooCommand = function(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    };
    window.MyApp.Core.Contracts.Commands.FooCommand.type = "MyApp.Core.Contracts.Commands.FooCommand";
})(window.MyApp = window.MyApp || {});
```

**Update**
Code completion didnt work with old solution, had to add the staticly declare each closure seperate for it to work correctly

Comment: p.Access == vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic is what I was looking for ... thanks!

Comment: I got an upvote so I take the opportunity to link to my blog that covers this area in more depth  http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/02/05/typed-javascript-contracts-using-t4-templates/